# How to return documents by mongoose find?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bluebird

In my application, Im using mongoose with bluebird like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

In the same file, Im holding an function which searches for *"appointment"-documents* in the Database. The return of that function should be the resulting array of found documents and not a promise, a query or something else.

But unfortunately, it seems like the program will jump back to the calling function before the promise will get fulfilled. So how can I handle that?

Here's my function in the current state:

```
get_intersecting_appointment: function(appointment) {

        var appointmentQuery = AppointmentModel.find({
            $and: [{
                    begin: {
                        $lte: appointment.begin
                    }
                },
                {
                    end: {
                        $gte: appointment.end
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

        return appointmentQuery.then(function(appointments) {
            debug("Found appointments:");
            debug(appointments);

            if (appointments) {
                return appointments;
            } else {
                return [];
            }

        });


    },
```

Hint: The calling function prints the "next debug-outputs" before the inner `debug("Found appointments:")`; from above. Lets say, the calling function looks like this:

```
appointment_is_available: function(appointment) {

        var appointments = dbcon.get_intersecting_appointment(appointment);
        //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per `Node.js` nature you can use callback to resolve such type of issue

use `callback`

As per your code I tried to add callback

```
get_intersecting_appointment: function(appointment,callback) {

    var appointmentQuery = AppointmentModel.find({
        $and: [{
            begin: {
                $lte: appointment.begin
            }
        }, {
            end: {
                $gte: appointment.end
            }
        }]
    });

    return appointmentQuery.then(function(appointments) {
        debug("Found appointments:");
        debug(appointments);

        if (appointments) {
            callback(null,appointments);
        } else {
            callback(null,[]);
        }

    });

},
```

//add callback function while calling it

```
appointment_is_available: function(appointment) {

        var appointments = dbcon.get_intersecting_appointment(appointment,function(err,result){
            if(!err){
                consoole.log(result)
            }
        });
        //...
}
```

**Update**

You can also use `Promise` or [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: Well even if this would work properly, I would prefer to de-async the code since the calling function will get called by another function and I just want to avoid to build a long chain of functions which passes a callback. Also I have to woirk with the result within the `appointment_is_available` function since I just want to return an boolean-value from it. If I would get just an callback, the function will return before the callback will get called, so same problem here (there is no way to wait for a callback like "than" or something IMHO).

Comment: Well,  so you can use `Promise` or [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: Yeah thats the origin-question: My above example uses promise with a then-method but it won't wait for the result of the then(...) before returning to the calling function which is not the behaviour I expected. So how can I wait here for the fulfilling of the promise?

Comment: As per your code, your outer function is not promise that's why outer is going to execute before.

You can make it promise also

Comment: Well I will not handle any promises within the calling function but just resolve all promises or queries within the `get_intersecting_appointment` function so I will get the real documents as a result in the `appointment_is_available`. The calling function should not deal with any promise behaviour but only the concret data.

Answer (score 0):

```
var appointmentQuery = AppointmentModel.find({
            $and: [{
                    begin: {
                        $lte: appointment.begin
                    }
                },
                {
                    end: {
                        $gte: appointment.end
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

replace the above code with the following

```
var appointmentQuery = AppointmentModel.find({
            $and: [{
                    begin: {
                        $lte: appointment.begin
                    }
                },
                {
                    end: {
                        $gte: appointment.end
                    }
                }
            ]
        }).exec();
```

**NOTE-** It's a good practice to use `.exec()` after every mongoose operation to use that with promise. Because the `.exec()` returns a pending promise.

Now coming to the place where you use this function is something like `var appointments = dbcon.get_intersecting_appointment(appointment);`. See here `dbcon.get_intersecting_appointment(appointment)` this returns a promise which you are assigning to a variable and it's asynchronous hence the next line is being executed before this completes. One more thing the value returned from `.then()` can only be accessed inside another chained `.then`. you can't simply assign the value returned from `.then()` to a global variable. You have to chain another `then` to utilize that value. You need a slight modification where you are calling `dbcon.get_intersecting_appointment(appointment)`. you need to do it like this way

```
dbcon.get_intersecting_appointment(appointment).then(function(res){
    //res is either empty array or the result array
    //rest of your code here

})
```

Comment: I also tried this approach, but it results in the same behaviour like the version from my question. Thats strange since exec() returns indeed an promise but the line `return appointmentQuery.then(...)` will still wont wait for the result of the `then` and will jump back immediately. :(